# Forms are minimized on FormShow: random behaviour in Delphi application. Any idea?

Tags: delphi, forms, minimize

I am experiencing an hard-to-track problem: when showing new forms (I create and show them at runtime) sometimes the form is minimized.

I don't understand why, I say this problem in xp, Vista and 7.

I tried to create samples to isolate the problem but on the samples I cannot reproduce it (=the forms always show not minimized).

What happens is:

in my application I create and show many forms (user clicks on menu item - a form is created and shown). Sometimes, randomly, the form is also minimized in the application bar. So i need to click on it and it is restored again...

Does anyone has a clue of why this happens? If I have an hint at least I can try to find and fix the problem.

I use Delphi 2009 and DevExpress VCL.

Comment: Are you using any code/components that keep the store the form position so it stays in the same position when it is recreated?

Comment: I have a feeling the form isn't getting minimized so much as going to the background.  Is that possible?  In other words, immediately after a new form is launched, you still see the old one, because the new one is sitting behind it?

Comment: yes I use code to restore the form size (not position).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At runtime:

```
Form := TMyForm.Create;
Form.Show;
Form.WindowState := fsNormal;
```

If you don't use any state-saving components, then better reverse last two actions:

```
Form := TMyForm.Create;
Form.WindowState := fsNormal;
Form.Show;
```

Comment: Yes Yes Yes. This answer (that at first I ignored) reviewd 6 months later gave me the clue. My problem was that I was restoring WindowsState, so if the user closed the application with any window minimized it was restored as minimized. So I used the answer anyway because I was rstoring in formshow (no reason to do in FormShow so i moved in FormCreate), anyway that "focus" on WindowState was useful. Thanks.